# How to change line spacing in DocX (docx.codeplex.com)

Tags: novacode-docx

I have a `Paragraph` object from the C# library [DocX](https://docx.codeplex.com) and am trying in vain to set the `LineSpacing` property but it has no effect?

```
internal static Paragraph StandardFormat(this Paragraph p)
{
    p = p.FontSize(12);

    p.LineSpacing = 1.5f;

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the `LineSpacing` property is for but that was a red herring. The fix was to use the `SetLineSpacing` method:

```
internal static Paragraph StandardFormat(this Paragraph p)
{
    p = p.FontSize(12);

    p.SetLineSpacing(LineSpacingType.Line, 1.5f);

    return p;
}
```

Comment: You saved my day man! Thank you very much! One more thing, try all the LineSpacingType options, in my case LineSpacingType.After solved my problem